# After restore from a deleted database, get error "User does not have permission to perform this action." when execute sp_updatestats

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a V12 azure database.  It can run with execute sp_updatestats no problem

I deleted the database by accident (IT'S a mistake).

So I went to the management portal and restored the database from the [DELETED DATABASES] to the original server.  It took about 1 hour to restore.

After restore the database seems fine except one thing, If I execute sp_updatestats, it will throw out a error:

User does not have permission to perform this action.

Also, I found out that, the restored database's owner_sid is not the original server principal user anymore.

What is the proper way to fix this?

Comment: What server principal did the old database's owner_sid map to? I don't have experience with Azure, but if this was on premises SQL Server, I'd do `alter authorization on database::[yourDB] to [desiredServerPrincipal]`.